# How to use the omaha protocol to get latest stable version of google chrome for Mac and Windows?

Tags: google-chrome

I have noticed recently that when using the official download link offered by google to pull latest version of google chrome for mac, it was giving me old version of the dmg file. I assume after opening google chrome it uses the keystone agent to query some server to pull the latest version files. Could some one explain how google chrome/keystone agent (with what headers) queries for the download url?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the current Omaha protocol doc at https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/doc/ServerProtocolV3.md. Craft a XML document with your need and POST it to a valid update check endpoint, you will get the available URL for downloading. The rest is download and save to file.

My example script for Windows in Python: https://gist.github.com/CrendKing/21cd2fbc8af8d932b5d6.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helps!! also how reliable is chrome when extracted using this way. I mean it should be similar to the google chrome copy that we get if we download from the official website right?

Comment: It is the same stable version you download using the installer. If you want the beta and dev channel version, change that `tag` value. Read the protocol doc for more details.